# open cv can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

Tags: python, file, path, opencv

I am creating a face detection algorithm which should take in images from a folder as input but I get this error:

```
import dlib
import argparse
import cv2
import sys
import time

import process_dlib_boxes

# construct the argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', default=r"C:\Users\awais\OneDrive\Documents\Greenwich Uni work\Face detec work\images folder",
                    help='path to the input image')
parser.add_argument('-u', '--upsample', type=float,
                    help='factor by which to upsample the image, default None, ' +
                          'pass 1, 2, 3, ...')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

# read the image and convert to RGB color format
image = cv2.imread(args['input'])
image_cvt = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# path for saving the result image
save_name = f"outputs/{args['input'].split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]}_u{args['upsample']}.jpg"
# initilaize the Dlib face detector according to the upsampling value
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
```

i get this error:

```
[ WARN:0@0.138] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('C:\Users\awais\OneDrive\Documents\Greenwich Uni work\Face detec work\images folder'): can't open/read file: check file path/integrity
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\awais\OneDrive\Documents\Greenwich Uni work\Face detec work\face_det_image.py", line 20, in <module>
    image_cvt = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Comment: welcome. please take the [tour] and review [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is that `cv2.imread` is returning `None` because it is unable to read the input image. This can happen if the file path provided to `cv2.imread` is incorrect or if the file does not exist.

You can try printing the value of `args['input']` to make sure it is correct and points to a valid image file. You can also try using the `os.path.isfile` function to check if the file exists before trying to read it. Here is an example:

```py
import dlib
import argparse
import cv2
import sys
import time
import os

import process_dlib_boxes

# construct the argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', default=r"C:\Users\awais\OneDrive\Documents\Greenwich Uni work\Face detec work\images folder",
                    help='path to the input image')
parser.add_argument('-u', '--upsample', type=float,
                    help='factor by which to upsample the image, default None, ' +
                         'pass 1, 2, 3, ...')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

# check if the input file exists
if not os.path.isfile(args['input']):
    print(f"Error: The file {args['input']} does not exist")
    sys.exit(1)

# read the image and convert to RGB color format
image = cv2.imread(args['input'])
image_cvt = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
# path for saving the result image
save_name = f"outputs/{args['input'].split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]}_u{args['upsample']}.jpg"
# initilaize the Dlib face detector according to the upsampling value
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
```

Comment: You're right, it says the path doesn't exist but I don't understand why, I changed the path to a folder containing more than 1 image and before that, the path was for 1 image which wasn't in a folder and it was working

Answer (score 0):

`imread()` is meant to read single image files, not entire folders.

You must pass a path to a file, not a path to an entire directory.

You passed a path to a directory. That is why `imread()` failed.